# CMB2 not working in my WordPress theme

Tags: plugins

I followed the instructions given in this [blog](https://getflywheel.com/layout/how-to-create-custom-meta-boxes-with-cmb2/) to set the CMB2 plugin, but it is not working in my case.

theme-meta-function.php →

```
    <?php
/**
 * Include and set up custom metaboxes and fields. (Make sure you copy this file outside the CMB2 directory)
 *
 * Be sure to replace all instances of 'yourprefix_' with your project's prefix.
 * http://nacin.com/2010/05/11/in-wordpress-prefix-everything/
 *
 * @category YourThemeOrPlugin
 * @package  Demo_CMB2
 * @license  http://www.opensource.org/licenses/gpl-license.php GPL v2.0 (or later)
 * @link     https://github.com/WebDevStudios/CMB2
 */

/**
 * Get the bootstrap! If using the plugin from wordpress.org, REMOVE THIS!
 */



add_action( 'cmb2_admin_init', 'register_testimonial_metabox' );
/**
 * Hook in and add a testimonial metabox. Can only happen on the 'cmb2_admin_init' or 'cmb2_init' hook.
 */
function register_testimonial_metabox() {

 // Start with an underscore to hide fields from custom fields list
    $prefix = '_yourprefix_'; //note, you can use anything you'd like here

/**
 * Start field groups here
 */

// This first field group tells WordPress where to put the fields. In the example below, it is set to show up only on Post_ID=10

$cmb_demo = new_cmb2_box( array(
        'id'            => $prefix . 'metabox',
        'title'         => __( 'Homepage Custom Fields', 'cmb2' ),
        'object_types'  => array( 'page', ), // Post type
        'show_on'      => array( 'id' => array( 10, ) ), // Specific post IDs to display this metabox
        ) );


$cmb_demo->add_field( array(
    'name' => __( 'Testimonial Author', 'cmb2' ),
    'desc' => __( 'Who is the testimonial from', 'cmb2' ),
    'id'   => $prefix . 'author', //Note, I renamed this to be more appropriate
    'type' => 'textarea_small',
    ) );

$cmb_demo->add_field( array(
    'name'    => __( 'Testimonial', 'cmb2' ),
    'desc'    => __( 'add the testimonial here', 'cmb2' ),
    'id'      => $prefix . 'testimonial', //Note, I renamed this to be more appropriate
    'type'    => 'wysiwyg',
    'options' => array( 'textarea_rows' => 5, ),
    ) );

    $cmb_demo->add_field( array(
    'name' => __( 'Author Image', 'cmb2' ),
    'desc' => __( 'Upload an image or enter a URL.', 'cmb2' ),
    'id'   => $prefix . 'image', //Note, I renamed this to be more appropriate
    'type' => 'file',
    ) );
}
```

then I have included like this in the functions.php →

```
require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/inc/lib/theme-meta-functions.php');
```

But not a single meta is appearing the post →
https://www.screencast.com/t/Bvihe62fZMV

I forget to mention that the **plugin is already installed** in the **Wordpress**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution →

```
'object_types'  => array( 'page', ), // Post type
        'show_on'      => array( 'id' => array( 10, ) ), // Specific post IDs to display this metabox
```

the above was the reason why it was not working on a post.

I just added post and added it here →

```
'object_types'  => array( 'page', ), // Post type
```

and deleted this line →

```
 'show_on'      => array( 'id' => array( 10, ) ), // Specific post
```

It all started to work, and there was no issue in the plugin or any piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

Change `$prefix = '_yourprefix_';`  to  `$prefix = '_wp';`

or add the code below directly to functions.php

```
add_action( 'cmb2_admin_init', 'register_testimonial_metabox' );

function register_testimonial_metabox() {

$prefix = '_wp'; 

$cmb_demo = new_cmb2_box( array(
'id'            => $prefix . 'metabox',
'title'         => __( 'Homepage Custom Fields', 'cmb2' ),
'object_types'  => array( 'page', ), // Post type
'show_on'      => array( 'id' => array( 10, ) ),
) );


$cmb_demo->add_field( array(
'name' => __( 'Testimonial Author', 'cmb2' ),
'desc' => __( 'Who is the testimonial from', 'cmb2' ),
'id'   => $prefix . 'author', 
) );

$cmb_demo->add_field( array(
'name'    => __( 'Testimonial', 'cmb2' ),
'desc'    => __( 'add the testimonial here', 'cmb2' ),
'id'      => $prefix . 'testimonial',
'type'    => 'wysiwyg',
'options' => array( 'textarea_rows' => 5, ),
) );

$cmb_demo->add_field( array(
'name' => __( 'Author Image', 'cmb2' ),
'desc' => __( 'Upload an image or enter a URL.', 'cmb2' ),
'id'   => $prefix . 'image', 
'type' => 'file',
) );
}
```

Comment: Nothing appeared.

Comment: did you added the code to your functions.php ?

Comment: are you using a child theme ?

Comment: No child theme. yes added to functions.php.

Comment: [see here](https://www.screencast.com/t/vcy5azlqGWvY)

Comment: try the official tutorial - https://github.com/CMB2/CMB2/wiki/Basic-Usage

Comment: there also the same information is given.

Comment: did you tried this in your theme and did that worked?

Comment: I think the first step to troubleshoot this issue is to try the same code in a different theme and then if it works on a different theme you will know the issue is on your theme - then you can start to debug the theme and see where the problem is coming from. In case the code is not working in a WordPress Default Theme you should open a support ticket on the plugin wordpress page

Comment: I tried this in a default theme. there also it didnt worked.

Comment: So it is almost clear that there is a problem with the plugin, you should contact the plugin author - https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/cmb2

Comment: How come such a famous plugin not working onkly for me.

Comment: I think the problem here → `'object_types'  => array( 'page', ), // Post type
`

Comment: I wanted to show this on the posrt page.

Comment: can you Please delete the answer so that i can delete the question?